# TeXstudio wrong indentation after certain environments

Tags: tables, lists, indentation, texstudio, multicol

I have the impression that Texstudio struggles to indent text following the end of a list (in code, works fine when built of course). Here's what I get with auto-indentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item 
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 
        \end{itemize}
    \item 
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Can I fix this somehow?

Edit: I've just noticed that this happens not only for lists but also for other environments, like:
- tabular
- tabularx
- center
- multicol
But **not** for:
- align
- flalign
- equation

Comment: which version of texstudio do you use? I get the last `\item` aligned with `\end{itemize}`

Comment: TeXstudio 2.12.6 (hg 6632:7777b2b8a906)

Comment: Same version as me. Strange....